# Push method adds more to array than expected?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am adding objects to array dynamically and came across this problem. When I hit save(), the script adds not only the last user input but also the whole array itself. At the end there is a really messed up array list. Here is the function that adds the user input to the array:

```
function Save() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var rgb = document.getElementById("colordisplay").innerHTML;
    var opacity = document.getElementById("div").style.opacity;
    colors.push({
        name_prop:name,
        rgb_prop:rgb,
        opacity_prop:opacity
    });
    //pass the object to the drop down list
    var select = document.getElementById("selectColor");
    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        var opt = colors[i].name_prop;
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.innerHTML = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
        console.log(colors);
    }
}
```

[Here is a JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/iYaZoNas/1/) :  To see the problem add some input to the name text field and hit save. Repeat this step couple of times to see the pile up effect.
To summarize it I need the script to add only the last input and not duplicate the array over and over again. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem with the `push` method. You're looping over the entire `colors` array every time you run `Save`, so it's re-adding the elements you previously added.

Try this:

```
function Save() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var rgb = document.getElementById("colordisplay").innerHTML;
    var opacity = document.getElementById("div").style.opacity;
    colors.push({
        name_prop:name,
        rgb_prop:rgb,
        opacity_prop:opacity
    });

    //pass the object to the drop down list
    var select = document.getElementById("selectColor");
    var opt = name;
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.innerHTML = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
    console.log(colors);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Push isn't the problem. Every pass through the function you are adding the entire list to the dropdown. Just add the new object. Don't loop through colors every time.

If you look at the output of console.log you'll see that the array is the correct length and contains the correct objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `for` loop and just append the new element.

```
/*for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {*/
    //var opt = colors[i].name_prop;
var opt = name;
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.innerHTML = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
    console.log(colors);
/*  }*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is populated correctly, it is the population of the select list that you are doing wrong. Just add the new colour (rather than looping all array elements, add adding them each time you save):

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectColor");
var el = document.createElement("option");
el.innerHTML = name;
el.value = name;
select.appendChild(el);
```

[Here is your updated example](http://jsbin.com/ikEyoDA/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

you should clear select list before append the colors object

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectColor");
        select.innerHTML="";//clear the select list 
        for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        var opt = colors[i].name_prop;
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.innerHTML = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
        console.log(colors);
      }
```